# How can I get the previous week in Python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-datetime

I am currently getting the current week starting on Monday and ending on Sunday but how can I get the previous week starting on Monday and ending on Sunday? Here is what I have now for the current week:

```
>>> import datetime
>>> today = datetime.date.today()
>>> weekday = today.weekday()
>>> start_delta = datetime.timedelta(days=weekday)
>>> start_of_week = today - start_delta
>>> week_dates = []
>>> for day in range(7):
...     week_dates.append(start_of_week + datetime.timedelta(days=day))
...
>>> week_dates
[datetime.date(2013, 10, 28), datetime.date(2013, 10, 29), datetime.date(2013, 10, 30),     datetime.date(2013, 10, 31), datetime.date(2013, 11, 1), datetime.date(2013, 11, 2), datetime.date(2013, 11, 3)]
>>> week_dates[0], week_dates[-1]
(datetime.date(2013, 10, 28), datetime.date(2013, 11, 3)) <--- Monday, Sunday
```

Comment: Do the same thing but go back another 7 days?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Build array of dates in last week, this week and next week](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17611774/build-array-of-dates-in-last-week-this-week-and-next-week)

Comment: Python magic is weird sometimes. I never knew this before, that 
`print(datetime.datetime.now() - datetime.timedelta(days=9))` output:
`2022-03-14 17:43:54.239033`

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Just add `weeks=1` to your `start_delta` to subtract an additional week:

```
>>> start_delta = datetime.timedelta(days=weekday, weeks=1)
```

So, for today (Wednesday, October 30, 2013), `start_delta` will be 9 days (back to last Monday, October 21, 2013).

```
>>> start_delta
datetime.timedelta(9)
>>> start_of_week = today - start_delta
>>> start_of_week
datetime.date(2013, 10, 21)
```